# Mongoid: using more than one database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB and MongoID in a rails app, how can some models be a part of a different mongo database on the same server? How would I accomplish something like that? I've run into the same problem with mysql before and couldn't find a reasonable solution.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The newest versions of Mongoid support this. See [the docs](http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/replication.html).

Snippets:

config/mongoid.yml:

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  slaves:
    - host: localhost
      port: 27018
    - host: localhost
      port: 27019
  databases:
    secondary:
      database: secondary_database
      host: localhost
      port: 27020
      slaves:
        - host: localhost
          port: 27021
        - host: localhost
          port: 27022
```

In your model:

```
class Business
  include Mongoid::Document
  set_database :secondary
end
```

Comment: Config file not applicable to "newest" version of Mongoid anymore. Also link to docs has changed.

Comment: It looks like `secondary` config was removed. https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/