# Multi-domain Rails app with multiple MongoDB's: Choose DB based on the domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, multiple-databases

I have a multi-domain Rails 4 app where the `request.domain` of the http request determines which functionality I expose a given visitor to. A visitor can sign up through [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). During the `user` creation a `user.domain` field will be filled in with the domain he signed up for, and he will then only have access to this particular domain and its functionality.

Question:

Each domain in my app should be served by its own MongoDB database. If `user.domain == 'domain1.com'` the `user` object, as well as all objects that `belongs_to` it, should be stored in the database that serves *domain1.com*. How do I set this up?

Complication 1:

I do not only interact with my database through [Mongoid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid), but also through mongo Shell methods like [db.collection.insert()](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/db.collection.insert/). I need to have the correct database connection in both cases. Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :connect_to_db
  def connect_to_db
    domain = request.domain
    # Establish connection
  end
end
```

Complication 2:

A lot of the database interaction happens outside the MVC context. I need to have the correct database connection in e.g. a [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) context. Example:

```
class MyJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(domain)
    connect_to_db(domain)
    User.all.each do |user|
      ...
    end
  end

  def connect_to_db(domain)
    # Establish connection
  end
end
```

Potentially relevant SO answers:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5798119) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16412428/1413388) suggests that you can apply a `set_database` or `store_in session` method on a model level, but this would not be sufficient for me, because models are shared between my domains. Various stragegies have also been discussed in [this Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/Rp64Tvjwtbk).